# Warning message after running emmeans in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans, error-message

I was doing a tukey-adjusted comparison among 3 levels of a factor (“Factor B”) using the `emmeans()` function in R and got the following warning:

> ```
> Warning message:
>
> In sweep(X, 1, sqrt(weights), "*") :
>   STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'
> ```

I do not really understand it and a quick google search did not really resolve it. Can someone explain to me what the problem is? I also seem to get this warning when I rerun old code where I previously used `emmeans()` and do not remember seeing this warning.

The code is as follows:

```
library(emmeans)
library(nlme)

z <- varIdent(form= ~ 1 | FactorA*FactorB)
G7 <- gls(Y~FactorA*FactorB, data=set, weights=z)

emm <- emmeans(G7, specs = pairwise ~ FactorB|FactorA, type = "response")
```

Running this gives me:

> ```
> Warning message:
>
> In sweep(X, 1, sqrt(weights), "*") :
>   STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'
> ```

The actual output is, however, what I want. It compares the levels of Factor B for each level of Factor A seperately and the result looks reasonable.

Many thanks in advance